# Computing the percentage of values in an array

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following array:

```
[ratings] => Array
 (
      [0] => 3
      [1] => 3
      [2] => 2
      [3] => 3
      [4] => 3
      [5] => 1
      [6] => 3
      [7] => 4
      [8] => 5
 )
```

What would be the best and fastest way to get the the percentage of each rating. For example there are 9 ratings now, and 5 ratings of "3", so the percentage of rating "3" is 55.55%.

Comment: [array_count_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) and count() thats 90% of the work - go do the rest.

Comment: Wow, didn't know about array_count_values(). Excelent function! Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

although he probably has something already, this is what I came up with.

```
<?php
$array = array(3,3,2,3,3,1,3,4,5);

function array_avg($array, $round=1){
    $num = count($array);
    return array_map(
        function($val) use ($num,$round){
            return array('count'=>$val,'avg'=>round($val/$num*100, $round));
        },
        array_count_values($array));
}

$avgs = array_avg($array);

/*
 * You can access any average/count like:
 * echo "The count of 3 is: {$avgs[3]['count']}";
 * echo "The average of 3 is: {$avgs[3]['avg']}";
 */

echo '<pre>'.print_r($avgs,1).'</pre>';
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [3] => Array
        (
            [count] => 5
            [avg] => 55.6
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [count] => 1
            [avg] => 11.1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [count] => 1
            [avg] => 11.1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [count] => 1
            [avg] => 11.1
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [count] => 1
            [avg] => 11.1
        )
)
```

http://codepad.viper-7.com/yD9CQm

Comment: would it be hard to modify the function in order to return the percentage, and the count? For example, for rating "3", the percentage is 55.6 and the count is 5.

Comment: @Psyche updated. now returns an array for each number with the count and avg.

Answer (score 4):

```
function findPercentage($r, $ratings){
    $arr = array_count_values($ratings);
    return $arr[$r]/count($ratings) * 100;
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some explanation for your code? You know this site is not really a coding contest, we try to help people here.

Answer (score 1):

As commented, you can make use of the [`array_count_values`](http://php.net/array_count_values) and process with [`count`](http://php.net/count) with a simple iteration.

In my code-example I wrap this into a function of it's own:

```
$ratings = [3,3,2,3,3,1,3,4,5];

$percentages = function($ratings) {
    $total = count($ratings);
    $percentages = [];
    foreach(array_count_values($ratings) as $value => $count) {
        $percentages[$value] = $count / $total;
    }
    return $percentages;    
};

print_r($percentages($ratings));
```

Output ([Demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/bsC3ts)):

```
Array (
    [3] => 0.55555555555556
    [2] => 0.11111111111111
    [1] => 0.11111111111111
    [4] => 0.11111111111111
    [5] => 0.11111111111111
)
```

I hope this demonstrates it fairly well. And again (for the fun):

```
print_r($percentages(array_map('strval', $percentages($ratings))));
```

(`array_count_values()` can only count STRING and INTEGER values)

Output:

```
Array (
    [0.55555555555556] => 0.2
    [0.11111111111111] => 0.8
)
```

Answer (score 0):

`$avg = array_sum($a)/count($a)`

in Javascript:

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]; 
var avg = a.reduce(function(a,b){ return a+b })/a.length;
```

Comment: ok, but where did the OP say anything about javascript? may as well give him the answer in Fortran

Comment: thought it can be useful ... Yes I can give it in Pascal, C, C++, C#, Perl and even in SmallTalk and Assembeler for at least 20 processors  and in SQL too :) no joke! do you think PHP solution is fine? If Yes vote up please, not down :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// $ratings is your array

function findPercentage($r, $ratings){
$count = 0; // count number of particular ratings
    foreach ($ratings as $i){
        if ($i == $r) $count++;
}

return $count/count($ratings) * 100;

}
```

example:

```
echo findPercentages(3, $ratings);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$rating = array(3, 3, 5, 5, 3, 4);

$value = 0;
foreach ($rating as $i) {
    $value += $i;
}
$percentage = $value / count($rating);

echo $percentage;
```

==
**UPDATE**

I wrote small test:

```
$rating = array();

echo "create array".PHP_EOL;

for ($i = 0; $i < 100000; $i++) {
    $rating[] = rand(1, 5);
}


echo "foreach algorithm: ".PHP_EOL;
$time = microtime();

$value = 0;
foreach ($rating as $i) {
    $value += $i;
}
$percentage = $value / count($rating);


echo $percentage.PHP_EOL;
echo "time is ".(microtime() - $time).PHP_EOL;

echo "array_sum algorithm: ".PHP_EOL;
$time = microtime();

$avg = array_sum($rating)/count($rating);
echo "time is ".(microtime() - $time).PHP_EOL;
```

and result:

```
create array
foreach algorithm: 
2.99924
time is 0.017117
array_sum algorithm: 
time is 0.002819
```

Answer: use algorithm that wrote user @Reflective, use function **array_sum**